# OpenCvSharp Draw a line in a picturebox

Tags: c#, opencv

I want to draw a red line in this picture.
But why the line is not red and the background color is still exist?

```
`        
// where I load the image is 

pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\ZHAOLX\\Desktop\\TEst1\\20210805-IMG_1751.jpg");
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;

// the function click the picturebox:

void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender,MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Drawing.Point p = e.Location;
            PictureBox pic = (PictureBox)sender;
            Bitmap picbit = new Bitmap(pic.Image); // recording the raw data

            Console.WriteLine("X坐标：" + e.X.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Y坐标：" + e.Y.ToString());
            Mat picMat = ConvertFile.BitmapToMat(picbit);
            //OpenCvSharp.InputOutputArray.

            Cv2.Line(picMat, 0, e.Y, pic.Width, e.Y, 
            OpenCvSharp.Scalar.Red,10,LineTypes.AntiAlias);
            //Console.WriteLine("Y坐标：" + e.Y.ToString());
            pic.Image = ConvertFile.MatToBitmap(picMat);

        }
`
```

[I want get a red line but the color of line is backgroud's color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGmuO.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this bug.

That is because the bitmap to mat give the CV_8UC4 mat (which is 4 channels) and the alpha channel is 0(So it show the background of picturebox)

Solution:

```
   Mat picMat = ConvertFile.BitmapToMat(picbit);
   picMat = picMat.CvtColor(ColorConversionCodes.RGBA2RGB,3);
```

let picMat to be 3 channels mat